# can i share the same mysql db between xampp and mamp (mac amp)?

Tags: mysql, database, xampp, share, mamp

i'm doing some test with xampp and mamp (on macos x snow leopard), sometime i switch between them just to play around , the issue that each of them have their own db in separated location :

```
xampp in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/ 
mamp in /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/
```

I don't want to deal with 2 separated mysql db data, i just want to have one , so i can share it to both xampp and mamp (not at the same time). I can update my db without worrying to update another db. Is this implementation is possible ? Does anyone know how to do it without any conflict ?

i'm using mac (so it's mamp), but this can be implemented on other system as well.

THanX

Answer (score 2):

I did something like this on Linux. I needed to run two different versions of PHP but use one MySQL database. I had Apache/PHP installed in Linux as normal and I also installed XAMPP to run a different version of Apache/PHP.

Your setup is similar so the following should work so that both MAMP and XAMPP use the MAMP MySQL database.

I changed the PHP config in XAMPP to use my main MySQL db. Like so:

- Locate the file php.ini in XAMPP (mine was in the the etc/ folder of XAMPP).
- Open the file in a text editor of your choice and find the default socket it uses for MySQL.
- Change this to use the socket
  provided by MAMP.

  ```
   mysql.default_socket = /path/to/mamp/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  ```
- Save the file and restart Apache in XAMPP.
- There is no need to start MySQL in XAMPP anymore as PHP should use the socket connection from MAMP.
- XAMPP should now use the database from MAMP.

This *should* work :)

Comment: In my case it is the other way around. I need xampp because i want to run my site using a older mysql version (5.1). i tried to change the php.ini from MAMP, mysql.default_socket = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock. but it still refers to the database made in MAMP.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it  should be possible. Give a try to following technique.

You can start XAMPP. Now Your Apache and PHP of XAMPP will work with mysql of XAMPP.

You can start XAMPP then stop Apache and PHP service of XAMPP. Then start MAMP. Stop mysql service of MAMP. Now Yor Apache and PHP of MAMP will work with mysql of XAMPP.

Comment: Thanx, but they're still using different database file. The newly created database/tables only visible in one of them. Altering database only happen to one of them. The database file is different, like i wrote above , They're the folders where db files are stored. The solution is  to move the db file to new share location where both mysql(xampp and mamp) will point to. Also need to change some config files which store information about where the db files/data are stored then modify it so it can point to new location.